# Как синхронизировать работу двух фильтров?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Привет 
 
Есть 2 фильтра, которые я не могу синхронизировать. Как это можно сделать?

Как должно работать, я выбираю в первом фильтре чекбокс, появляются блоки связанные с ним, при выборе из второго филтра должны добавиться блоки связанные с ним, но при этом, блоки добавленные первым фильтром, должны оставться на месте.

Может через селектор это сделать можно? но как именно это сделать я не знаю.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var rubric = $('[data-rubric]');
  var rubric_items = $('.filter-rubric__item :checkbox');
  var tour = $('[data-tour]');
  var tour_items = $('.filter-session__item :checkbox');

  rubric_items.on('change', function() {
    var name = this.id;
    if ($('.filter-rubric__item :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        rubric.hide();
        $('[data-rubric=' + name + ']').show();
      } else {
        $('[data-rubric=' + name + ']').hide();
      }
    } else if ($('.filter-rubric__item :checkbox:checked').length > 1) {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('[data-rubric=' + name + ']').show();
      } else {
        $('[data-rubric=' + name + ']').hide();
      }
    } else {
      rubric.show();
    }
  });

  tour_items.on('change', function() {
    var name = this.id;
    if ($('.filter-session__item :checkbox:checked').length == 1) {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        tour.hide();
        $('[data-tour=' + name + ']').show();
      } else {
        $('[data-tour=' + name + ']').hide();
      }
    } else if ($('.filter-session__item :checkbox:checked').length > 1) {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('[data-tour=' + name + ']').show();
      } else {
        $('[data-tour=' + name + ']').hide();
      }
    } else {
      tour.show();
    }
  });

  function filter_event() {
    if ($('data-rubric') != name && $('data-tour') != name) {
      rubric.hide();
    } else {
      rubric.show();
    };
  }
});
```

```css
.filter__list--event {
  border-bottom: 0;
  padding: 25px 0 25px;
  margin: 0;
}
.filter__item {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.filter-session__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.filter-rubric__list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 12px;
}
.filter-rubric__label span {
  display: none;
}
.filter-rubric input {
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}
.filter-rubric__label {
  color: #979797;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  padding: 9px 0 14px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.filter-rubric__item:first-child .filter-rubric__label {
  padding: 3px 0 14px 0;
}
filter-rubric__label:before {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 9px;
  width: 16px;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .filter-rubric__label span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: 10px;
}
.filter-rubric__label span > svg {
  height: 15px;
  width: 16px;
  fill: #ff5711;
}
svg:not(:root) {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.timeWidth {
  width: 178px;
}
.time-message__event-info--purple {
  background-color: #eee5f4;
}
.time-message__event-info {
  min-height: 101px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.timeWidth {
  width: 178px;
}
.timeLeft__360min {
  left: 360px;
}
.timeLeft {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
.time-message__event-info--blue {
  background-color: #a9dcf6;
}
.time-message__event-info {
  min-height: 101px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
.time-message__event-info--pink {
  background-color: #fed5d5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="filter__list filter__list--event">
  <li class="dropdown filter__item js-no-close"><span data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle filter__name" aria-expanded="false">Выберите рубрику</span>
    <div class="dropdown-menu filter-rubric">
      <ul class="filter-rubric__list">
        <li class="filter-rubric__item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="rubric-1">
          <label for="rubric-1" class="filter-rubric__label">Наука<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-rubric__item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="rubric-2">
          <label for="rubric-2" class="filter-rubric__label">Спорт<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-rubric__item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="rubric-3">
          <label for="rubric-3" class="filter-rubric__label">Искусство<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="filter-rubric__item">
          <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="rubric-4">
          <label for="rubric-4" class="filter-rubric__label">Общие события<span><!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16 15" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16 15;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
</style>
<path d="M4.4,7l2.2,4c0,0,3.5-8.2,9.1-11C15.6,2,15,3.7,16,5.7c-2.4,0.5-7.5,6.4-9.1,9.3c-2.3-2.7-5-4.8-6.9-5.5L4.4,7z
 "></path>
</svg>
</span>
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown filter__item js-no-close"><span data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle filter__name" aria-expanded="false">Выбрать смену</span>
    <div class="dropdown-menu filter-session js-vertical-scroll my_dropdown vertical-dropdown">
      <ul class="filter-session__list">
        <div class="jspContainer">
          <div class="jspPane">
            <li class="filter-session__item">
              <input type="checkbox" name="1" id="session-1">
              <label for="session-1" class="filter-session__label">Мартовская смена</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filter-session__item">
              <input type="checkbox" name="2" id="session-2">
              <label for="session-2" class="filter-session__label">Апрельская смена</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filter-session__item">
              <input type="checkbox" name="3" id="session-3">
              <label for="session-3" class="filter-session__label">Углубленное изучение математики</label>
            </li>
            <li class="filter-session__item">
              <input type="checkbox" name="4" id="session-4">
              <label for="session-4" class="filter-session__label">Смена региональных Летних математических школ</label>
            </li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="time-message__event">
  <div data-rubric="rubric-1" data-tour="session-1" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--purple timeWidth">
    <div class="time-message__info">
      <p class="time-message__duration">07.00 - 08.00</p>
      <p class="time-message__name">Подъём и зарядка</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-rubric="rubric-1" data-tour="session-1" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--purple timeLeft timeLeft__30min timeWidth timeWidth__90min">
    <div class="time-message__info">
      <p class="time-message__duration">07.30 - 09.00</p>
      <p class="time-message__name">Завтрак для детей</p>
      <p class="time-message__description">(Столовая №1)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-rubric="rubric-1" data-tour="session-1" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--purple timeLeft timeLeft__60min timeWidth timeWidth__120min">
    <div class="time-message__info">
      <p class="time-message__duration">08.00 - 10.00</p>
      <p class="time-message__name">Завтрак для детей</p>
      <p class="time-message__description">(Столовая №1)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-rubric="rubric-2" data-tour="session-2" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--blue timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth">
    <div class="time-message__info">
      <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 10.00</p>
      <p class="time-message__name">Математика и геометрия</p>
      <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Смена кубок", группа А.</p>
      <p class="time-message__location">(ауд.Менделеева)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-rubric="rubric-2" data-tour="session-2" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--blue timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth">
    <div class="time-message__info">
      <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 10.00</p>
      <p class="time-message__name">Математика и геометрия</p>
      <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Смена кубок", группа Б.</p>
      <p class="time-message__location">(ауд.Менделеева)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-rubric="rubric-3" data-tour="session-3" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--pink timeLeft timeLeft__360min timeWidth timeWidth__180min">
    <div class="time-message__info">
      <p class="time-message__duration">09.00 - 12.00</p>
      <p class="time-message__name">Мастер-класс Павла Бурре</p>
      <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Спортивной надежды сборной",</p>
      <p class="time-message__location">(стадион "Шайба")</p>
    </div>
    <div class="js-close-subevent time-message__event-in" style="display: none;">
      <div class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--darkpink timeWidth timeWidth__30min">
        <div class="time-message__info">
          <p class="time-message__duration time-message__duration--sub">09.00 - 09.30</p>
          <p class="time-message__name time-message__name--sub">Сбор - выход</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--darkpink timeLeft timeLeft__30min-sub timeWidth timeWidth__90min">
        <div class="time-message__info">
          <p class="time-message__duration time-message__duration--sub">10.00 -11.30</p>
          <p class="time-message__name time-message__name--sub">Мастер класс на льду</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--darkpink timeLeft timeLeft__15min timeWidth timeWidth__15min">
        <div class="time-message__info">
          <p class="time-message__duration time-message__duration--sub">11.45 - 12.00</p>
          <p class="time-message__name time-message__name--sub">Возвра-щение</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="js-open time-message__open-close">Развернуть подсобытия</div>
  </div>
  <div data-rubric="rubric-2" data-tour="session-1" class="time-message__event-info time-message__event-info--blue timeLeft timeLeft__420min timeWidth">
    <div class="time-message__info">
      <p class="time-message__duration">10.00 - 11.00</p>
      <p class="time-message__name">Математические бои</p>
      <p class="time-message__description">Смена "Смена кубок", группа А.</p>
      <p class="time-message__location">(Лобби)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот, работает!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    if (!$("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked")) {
      $('.time-message__event-info').show();
    } else {
      $('.time-message__event-info').hide();
      $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var filter = $(this).attr('filter');
          var data = $(this).attr('data');
          $.each($('.time-message__event-info'), function() {
            var p = $(this);
            var fs = $(this).attr(filter).split(",");
            $.each(fs, function(index, value) {
              if (data == value) {
                p.show();
              }
            });
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```